# WSL problem : ERROR: unexpected error - [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Situation

Using WSL(Ubunts), I try to run Python. I use Pyenv + pipenv.
However, I sometimes faces the error message`ERROR: unexpected error - [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` as follows:

```sh
(vir_env) user@LAPTOP-N9:~/root$ pipenv --rm
Removing virtualenv (/home/user/root/.venv)...
⠋ Running...Error:  An error occurred while removing /home/user/root/.venv!
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/user/root/.venv/Lib/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'
```

```sh
(ver_env) user@LAPTOP-N9:~/root$ dvc repro hoge1/train.dvc
Verifying data sources in stage: 'data/hoge2/hoge3.pickle.dvc'
ERROR: failed to reproduce 'data/hoge2/hoge3.pickle.dvc': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/user/root/.dvc/cache/57/1d6255b95ef8123498djf839d'
```

#### What I tryied to solve the problem

By `chmod`, I permitted access to all files in root. In fact, `ls -a -l` shows that all directly or files are `drwxrwxrws` or `-rwxrwxrwx`.

Furthermore, I ran the command.

```
sudo umount /mnt/c
sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata
```

However, the situation didn't change.

#### Environment

Windows10 home
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft x86_64)
pyenv 1.2.21
pipenv version 2020.11.4
WSL2 (However, even in WSL1, same problem is occured)

#### Appendix (The way I built the WSL)

```sh
#Install pyenv
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# Get some packages
sudo apt install libffi-dev
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils xz-devel tk-dev
sudo apt-get update -y

#Install python
pyenv install 3.7.3
pyenv global 3.7.3

#Install pipenv 
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pipenv

#Install dvc
pip install dvc

#Others
sudo chmod -R a+rwx root
sudo chmod +x .venv/bin/python
pip install dvc
```

Comment: have you tried sudo for this command ? pipenv --rm   ; could you be more specific ? you have to resolve this permission issue ryt ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I tried sudo, but just `sudo: pipenv: command not found` is showed.

And I have to run the dvc for analysis, so it is necessary to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the directory.

```
sudo rm -r '/home/user/root/.venv/Lib/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'
```